# Breaking database replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2000

I am trying to break replication between two SQL 2000 databases.  Can this be done while the databases are live? or do they need to be taken offline?

Answer (score 1):

Delete publications from the Local Publications folder in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

To delete a publication

---

1.Connect to the Publisher in Management Studio, and then expand the server node.

2.Expand the Replication folder, and then expand the Local Publications folder.

3.Right-click the publication you want to delete, and then click Delete.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help, the databases should be online - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152757%28SQL.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396